# Mamp acting weird after upgrading to macOS Sierra

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache, mamp, macos-sierra

I am using Mamp Version 2.1.3 (2.1.3) but after upgrading to macOS Sierra Mamp started acting weird. Apache Server Started, MySQL started and when I use `http://localhost:8888/foldername` its URL changing to `http://localhost/foldername` with error unable to connect.

If I disable Wi-Fi then I get:

> Error establishing a database connection

I am trying to install New Wordpress and it's not working but all old websites are working.

Comment: I am experimented problem with sierrra and MySql Mamp. Perarps is due to the different manener for  sudo privilege in Sierra. Did you solve the issue?